# Implementing a Basic Neural Network to Perform Classification with Neuroph

Tags: java, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification, mlp, neuroph

I'm very new to neural networks, and decided to try implementing a basic one using Neuroph in Java to perform multiclass classification using Multilayer Perceptron.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MultiLayerPerceptron neuralNetwork = new MultiLayerPerceptron(2, 3, 3, 3);
        
        final BackPropagation rule = new BackPropagation();
        rule.setLearningRate(0.1);
        rule.setMaxError(0.001);
        rule.setMaxIterations(10000);
        
        neuralNetwork.setLearningRule(rule);
        
        final Layer softMaxLayer = neuralNetwork.getLayerAt(neuralNetwork.getLayersCount() - 2);
        final SoftMax max = new SoftMax(softMaxLayer);

        for (Neuron n : softMaxLayer.getNeurons()) 
            n.setTransferFunction(max);
        
//      for (Neuron n : this.getOutputNeurons())
//          n.setTransferFunction(new Linear());

        DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(2, 3);
        
        // Output contains only one instance of "1" to represent the class it belongs to
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{1, 0, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{1, 0, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{1, 0, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{0, 1}, new double[]{0, 1, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{0, 1}, new double[]{1, 0, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{1, 0}, new double[]{0, 0, 1});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{0, 0, 1});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{0, 1, 0});
        trainingSet.add(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{0, 1, 0});
        
        // Train the neural network on the training set
        neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);

        // Test the neural network on a new example
        neuralNetwork.setInput(0, 1);
        neuralNetwork.calculate();
        double[] output = neuralNetwork.getOutput();
        
        System.out.println(output[0]); // prints the probability of class 0
        System.out.println(output[1]); // prints the probability of class 1
        System.out.println(output[2]); // prints the probability of class 2
        
        System.out.println("\n\nTotal (=1?): " + (output[0] + output[1] + output[2]));
        System.out.println(neuralNetwork.getLearningRule().getTotalNetworkError());
    }
```

The output of the neural network should be a distribution, but the sum of it is slightly greater than or less than 1.

I generally tried to follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/softmax), with the idea being I implement a soft max layer before the output layer. I assume I made a basic mistake here, if anyone knows what I did incorrectly please let me know.

EDIT: Example output:

```
0.8514345496167552
0.23687369660618554
0.001890247376537854


Total (=1?): 1.0901984935994786
0.17265593270797627
```

(First three lines are the three output neuron values, followed by the sum of them, followed by the total network error).

Comment: Share the output and what is expected output.

Comment: @Bala I added an example output, though it's obviously going to vary since I didn't set a seed explicitly. The total printed (Total (=1?)) should add up to 1, since its the sum of the probabilities

Comment: bump. shoutout to Bala for whining about output and not offering a solution